# Filling between two lines and an arc

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, fillbetween, fill, arc

I want to fill the space between two lines and an arc with color like in the photo

[image]

This is the code I wrote:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,-3) arc (180:360:4cm and 2cm);
\draw (7,-2) -- (7,-5);
\draw (2,-2) -- (2,-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reusing [polyn's idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/647315/73317) from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/647306/73317) and the more explicit `arc[start angle=..., end angle=..., x radius=..., y radius=...]` syntax for arcs of ellipses:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
    \clip (2,-5) rectangle (7,-2);
    \fill[red!60] (1,-3)
      arc[start angle=180, end angle=360, x radius=4cm, y radius=2cm];
\end{scope}

\filldraw[red!60] (2,-3) rectangle ([yshift=-0.5\pgflinewidth] 7,-2);
\draw (1,-3) arc (180:360:4cm and 2cm);
\draw (2,-2) -- (2,-5) (7,-2) -- (7,-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `\filldraw` rather than `\fill` for the filled rectangle in order not to leave a thin unfilled space above the first filled region (alternatively, one could use e.g. `\fill[red!60] (2,-3.5) rectangle (7,-2);`). Since this would paint `0.5\pgflinewidth` higher than the vertical lines, I corrected this with the `yshift`. Here is how it looks with `line width=3pt`:

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear that; you can upvote [polyn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/647315/73317) for the idea. ;-)